# Does cow urine have medicinal properties?

Tags: antibiotics, excreta

It is a common belief in India that cow urine has medicinal properties.

It is said to be anti-biotic.

It cures diabetes, cancer and many other diseases if not all.

Because this is biology I would like to focus on the anti-biotic property and set aside other claims cos they many be related to medicine and not biology.

Is it anti-biotic?

Does urine not cause infections?

Especially since it is applied the belly of new born babies by orthodox Hinuds.

Comment: it's a question for skeptics.se

Comment: there's a bunch of questions on skeptics on this topic already, for example this one : https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36282/is-there-a-hindu-cult-in-india-that-drink-cow-urine-to-cure-diseases

Comment: @gilleain Note that only asks is such a practice exists not the medical validity of it.

Comment: Don't use these medicines please. It only goes into the vicious cycle of spreading more fraud.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question anomdsgf. There are substances present in *Bos taurus* urine that promote antimicrobial activity. Studies like [this](http://ijpsr.com/bft-article/antibacterial-activity-of-cow-urine-against-some-pathogenic-and-non-pathogenic-bacteria/?view=fulltext) and [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317746457_Comparison_of_antimicrobial_larvicidal_and_anthelmintic_activity_of_curcuma_aromatica_salisb_Cow_urine_extract) have shown how the urine can inhibit the growth of certain bacterial strains.

However, with all that said, *Bos taurus* urine could still contain other harmful bacteria that are not inhibited simply because it was excreted out of a cows urethra and could cause infections. Read more on possible harmful effects [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23777721).